# additional of features decrease the accuracy of the model

Tags: machine-learning, python, random-forest

I am using sklearn's random forests module to predict a binary target variable based on 166 features. When I increase the number of dimensions to 175 the accuracy of the model decreases (from accuracy = 0.86 to 0.81 and from recall = 0.37 to 0.32) .

I would expect more data to only make the model more accurate, especially when the added features were with business value.

I built the model using sklearn in python. Why the new features did not get weight 0 and left the accuracy as it was ?

Comment: train set accuracy? test? cross validation?

Comment: train set accuracy

Comment: Have you set the same random seed when selecting training/test sets?

Comment: yes. I have not changed anything but the dataset